# Non-Towered Airport Operation Logs

Tags: airport, faa

Do general aviation non-towered airports have to submit any types of logs to the FAA regarding total number of take-offs and landings in a given year?

I'm trying to figure out how busy a small airstrip near a property might be, I'm not having any luck getting the airstrip owner on the phone.

Thank you!

Comment: Which airport are you looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the airport at http://www.airnav.com/airports

It'll show info such as:

Airport Operational Statistics

Aircraft based on the field:        66

Single engine airplanes:        65

Multi engine airplanes:     1

Aircraft oper  ations:  avg 70/day *

52%     transient general aviation

48%     local general aviation

- for 12-month period ending 07 April 2015

Answer (score 0):

If it is non-towered it is highly unlikely that such records exist since this sort of data would typically be gathered by ATC personnel.  I would recommend networking with some local pilots to get a subjective measure of its use.

Answer (score 0):

Officially there is no regulation about this and I have never encountered anything official on it in practice.

However some airports both towered and un-towered are required to collect a small landing fee typically imposed by the local municipality, of which there may be a record of. You may need to go to the local municipality or controlling authority to get the info.

You can [get an idea from here as well](https://flightaware.com/live/airport/KDYL) but keep in mind this is only IFR/Flight Following/"in the system" flights.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is for US only, since the question is tagged FAA*

I don't know how the information is collected, but if you google "air operations xxx" where xxx is the FAA identifier for your airport, you'll find a bunch of sites that report this information.

For example, go to https://www.fltplan.com, select "Airport/FBO info", find your airport, scroll down to the tabbed section above the runway info and select 'aircraft data'.

AOPA has similar info: go to https://www.aopa.org/destinations/, find your airport, then look for the section "Aircraft & Activity".

https://skyvector.com also has this - click on the Airports button at the top left, find your airport, then look for "Operational Statistics".

Answer (score 0):

[Airnav](http://www.airnav.com/airports/) and other sites have usage data on all US airports, including non-towered ones, so someone is collecting and reporting this information somewhere.

I've read (can't remember where) that one should always use one's tail number at least once on CTAF so the airport doesn't miss out on their fair share of FAA subsidy funds, which is probably connected.  My best guess is the airport owners (or at least some of them) are recording CTAF to count tail numbers for when they have to submit their official usage data.

Comment: Of course, there are often a lot of no-radio operations at such airports as well.

Comment: @FredLarson Good point; such traffic may not be reported if there's no other counting mechanism, such as someone (or a video camera) watching the runway.